# Scipy LowLevelCallable with "nested" functions?

Tags: python, c, scipy, cython

"Nested" is possibly not the best terminology of what I am intending to do, but the problem is the following: I have an integral of a function, where the value of the function at every point depends on another integral. In particular, in the code below, evaluation of `spatial_contrib` at a point `(x,y)` assumes that a `func` is integrated in the variable `u`, parametrically depending on `(x,y)`

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad, nquad
import os, ctypes
from scipy import LowLevelCallable
import time

lib = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.abspath('lambda_int.so'))
lib.f.restype = ctypes.c_double
lib.f.argtypes = (ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double))
c = ctypes.c_double(1.0)
user_data = ctypes.cast(ctypes.pointer(c), ctypes.c_void_p)

func = LowLevelCallable(lib.f, user_data)

def spatial_contrib(x,y):
    u_integral = lambda x, y: quad(func, 0,1, args=(x,y))
    return ( np.exp(-(x**2 + y**2)) )/(2 * np.pi) * u_integral(x,y)[0]

def outer_integral(xa,ya,xb,yb,R):
    return 9* spatial_contrib(xa,ya) * spatial_contrib(xb-R,yb-R) * xa * ya * xb * yb / R**6

nquad(outer_integral, [ [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1], [0, 1] ], args =([1]))
```

In the very end, what I need to evaluate is the integral of `outer_integral`. This code uses the `LowLevelCallable` representation that I managed to define for `func`, with the C file simply being

```
/* lambda_int.c */
#include <math.h>

double f(int n, double *xx) {
    double u = xx[0];
    double x = xx[1];
    double y = xx[2];
    return -(log( u )/sqrt( 1-u*u ) ) * exp( 2*u*x*y/(1+u) - ( ((x-y)*(x-y)) * u*u) /(1-u*u) );
}
```

What I am wondering is whether it is possible to directly port either the `spatial_contrib`, or, ideally, `outer_integral` itself to a `LowLevelCallable`, even if it is already defined by an integration in Python?

Comment: Some profiling shows that this code spends 80% of its time integrating the innermost function. If you moved other pieces of this from SciPy to Python, therefore, you would get at most a 20% speedup. Still potentially worth doing, though.

Comment: I meant to say, "moved other pieces of this from Python to C."

Comment: See [ask]. It's unclear and unspecific. Elaborate porting the ```outer_integral``` to a ```LowLevelCallable```. You mean implementing ```outer_integral()``` entirely in C? Then you need to use QUADPACK directly.